# How do I create an Excel pie chart representing a simple 12-hour clock?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, date-time

I want to create a pie chart in Excel that represents a hand clock so that I can mark different time periods with different colors

Answer (score 4):

Simply make a column with numbers 1-12, and a column next to it with the number 1 in every cell. Now select all of these numbers, and insert a pie chart (there may be multiple options, select the one that shows equal slices).
[image]

Comment: It creates a chart with unequal slices, how do I edit it? I am on mobile

Comment: Even simpler: forget about the first column, just make a column of twelve 1's and make a pie chart